# Accessing C# method in a JavaScript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can i execute a C# method in a java script function? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. If you server is located in the USA, and a user visits your site from China, your C# code will execute in the USA, and your JavaScript code will execute several moments later (~ 500ms later probably) in China. When the JavaScript code begins its execution, the C# script that ran on the USA server will be long forgotten and terminated.

Your best bet is probably to communicate back to your server through [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), as [@David suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870295/accessing-c-method-in-a-javascript-function/3870309#3870309).

Comment: PageMethods is also working as Ajax.So I hope there will be no problem will come.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is fire an AJAX call that executes a C# method on the server, and hands back the result to the javascript.

AJAX is best handled with a javascript framework such as jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to access the server side methods in C# using Javascript
For all you need to use write a static function in the server side and call it using PageMethods.

at Client Side

```
   PageMethods.FunctionName(para1,pageMethodError)
    Here the condition is to pass pagemethoderroe as a parameter to return the function fails
         PageMethods.Get(Id,
                    function(result) {
                          $(.res).html(result);
                           }

                        }
                    }
                    , pageMethodError);

 pageMethodError=function(error){
  //code if failed
 //error will return error message
}
```

at server side

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

        public static object Get(string ID) {
            return "hai";
        }
```

for more abt the parameters  for a Page method 
plz refer to http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.3

This method is also using Ajax and it will post your request to the server and the server responds in the form of JSON [JavaScript object notation].So there is no problem if your server is located in US and accessing from China